# is there a free barcode 128 class for delphi (pdf)?

Tags: delphi, barcode

Is there a free alphanumeric barcode font or class that is compatible with Delphi "PowerPDF" component ?

code must be code128.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing, as PowerPdf has never supported any fonts other than the 14 [Standard Type 1 Fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdf#Standard_Type_1_Fonts) (see the [source code](http://powerpdf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/powerpdf/PdfFonts.pas?revision=1&view=markup)). There is no support for TrueType fonts, font embedding or such.

What you can do is switch to the successor of PowerPdf, the [Haru Free PDF Library](http://libharu.org/wiki/Main_Page). This supports encrypted TrueType fonts, font embedding and a few encodings other than the PDF `WinAnsiEncoding`. There are Delphi bindings. Together with a TTF that supports your barcode you should be able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Not a barcode class, but a GPL'ed TTF which can be embedded into your PDF file:

http://grandzebu.net/index.php?page=/informatique/codbar-en/codbar.htm

You also need an encoder, because you can't just type your characters with this font. But the VB6 and Excel encoding examples on that page can easily be transfered into Delphi code.

Answer (score 0):

As a tiny addition:
I used [this page](http://www.terryburton.co.uk/barcodewriter/generator/) to generate EPS barcodes (which can be embedded in PDF).
Actually: I wrote a [small article](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/11/30/generating-ean-13-barcode-eps-files-for-your-article-numbers/) on how to use this to generate a lot of EPS files using one small example.